# Error when trying to call pymode#rope#goto_definition() with vim's -c arg

Tags: vimscript, gvim, vimscript-python

If I call `gvim main.py -c "call cursor(41, 45)" -c "call pymode#rope#goto_definition()"`

Then I get this error about parenthesis:

```
"main.py" [unix] 54L, 1677C
Error detected while processing command line:
E107: Missing parentheses:pymodeC:\Users\me\key_state_manager.pyropeC:\Users\me\key_state_manager.pygoto_definition()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm trying to make a function for opening a definition in another gvim window.

[pymode link](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode)

Comment: I've just cobbled together a horrible solution by having a `~/goto_def.vim` file that contains `autocmd VimEnter * call pymode#rope#goto_definition()` and finally calling `gvim main.py -c "call cursor(41, 45)" -c "source ~/goto_def.vim"`

Comment: Could you copy/paste the error as text (rather than an image)? It's easier to read, and it facilitates searching, copy/pasting, etc.

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't copy an error from a gvim window because it doesn't let you highlight. However I'm actually having a hard time reproducing this now that I've fixed it. I've updated python and vim since then. The problem though was escaping `#` symbols. I'll post my answer now and type out the error manually :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I wasn't escaping `#` symbols. Here's my final function which opens a new gvim window for a function under the cursor.

```
function! NewGvimGotoDefin()
    let loc = ' -c "call cursor(' . line(".") . ', ' . getpos(".")[2] . ')" '
    let goto_def = ' -c "call pymode\#rope\#goto_definition()" '
    execute '!start /b gvim % ' . loc . goto_def
endfunction
```

And more generically: `gvim main.py -c "call cursor(41, 45)" -c "call pymode\#rope\#goto_definition()"`